# Spark sql to join two dataframes with no primary keys

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have the following 2 dataframes which i want to join to create new schema data:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("A011021","15","2020-01-01","2020-12-31","4"),("A011021","15","2020-01-01","2020-12-31","4"),("A011021","15","2020-01-01","2020-12-31","4"),("A011021","15","2020-01-01","2020-12-31","3")], ["rep_id","sales_target","start_date","end_date","st_new"])
df2.createOrReplaceTempView('df')
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+------+
rep_id         |sales_target|start_date|end_date  |st_new|
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+-------
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4     |
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4     |
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4     |
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|3     |
|A011022       |6           |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|3     |
|A011022       |6           |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|3     |
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+-------

df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("A011021","15","2020-01-01","2020-12-31","2020-01-01","2020-03-31"),("A011021","15","2020-01-01","2020-12-31","2020-04-01","2020-06-30"),("A011021","15","2020-01-01","2020-12-31","2020-07-01","2020-09-30"),("A011021","15","2020-01-01","2020-12-31","2020-10-01","2020-12-31")], ["rep_id","sales_target","start_date","end_date","new_sdt","new_edt"])
df2.createOrReplaceTempView('df2')
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
rep_id         |sales_target|start_date|end_date  |new_sdt    |new_edt   |
+--------------+------------+----------+----------------------+----------+
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|2020-01-01 |2020-03-31|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|2020-04-01 |2020-06-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|2020-07-01 |2020-09-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|2020-10-01 |2020-12-31|
|A011022       |6           |2020-01-01|2020-06-30|2020-01-01 |2020-03-31|
|A011022       |6           |2020-01-01|2020-06-30|2020-04-01 |2020-06-30|
+--------------+------------+----------+----------------------+----------+
```

When I run the query to join the two tables am getting duplicate results as below:

```
select ds1.*,ds2.st_new from df2 ds2
inner join df1 ds1
on ds2.rep_id=ds1.rep_id
where ds2.rep_id='A011021'

+--------------+------------+----------+----------+------+-----------+----------+
rep_id         |sales_target|start_date|end_date  |st_new|new_sdt    |new_edate |
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+------------------+----------+
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4     |2020-01-01 |2019-12-31|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4     |2020-01-01 |2019-12-31|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4     |2020-01-01 |2019-12-31|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|3     |2020-01-01 |2020-03-31|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4     |2020-04-01 |2020-03-31|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4     |2020-04-01 |2020-03-31|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4     |2020-04-01 |2020-03-31|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|3     |2020-04-01 |2020-06-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4     |2020-07-01 |2020-06-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4     |2020-07-01 |2020-06-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4     |2020-07-01 |2020-06-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|3     |2020-07-01 |2020-09-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4     |2020-10-01 |2020-09-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4     |2020-10-01 |2020-09-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4     |2020-10-01 |2020-09-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|3     |2020-10-01 |2020-12-30|
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+------------------+----------+
```

Is there a way to fetch only distinct new_sdt, new_edt for a given rep_id, quarterly data using the spark_sql, or pyspark functions, please help.

Expected result is :

```
select ds1.*,ds2.st_new from df2 ds2
inner join df1 ds1
on ds2.rep_id=ds1.rep_id

+--------------+------------+----------+----------+------+-----------+----------+
rep_id         |sales_target|start_date|end_date  |st_new|new_sdt    |new_edt |
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+------------------+----------+
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4     |2020-01-01 |2020-03-31|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4     |2020-04-01 |2020-06-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4     |2020-07-01 |2020-09-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|3     |2020-10-01 |2020-12-31|
|A011022       |6           |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|3     |2020-01-01 |2020-03-31|
|A011022       |6           |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|3     |2020-04-01 |2020-06-30|
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+------------------+----------+
```

Comment: what is `customer_number` column ?

Comment: Oh sorry it should be the rep_id, updated the query.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Allot unique id
2. Do a inner join
3. Drop the extra columns

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object InnerJoin {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess

    import spark.implicits._

    val df1 = List(
      ("A011021", "15", "2020-01-01", "2020-12-31", "4"),
      ("A011021", "15", "2020-01-01", "2020-12-31", "4"),
      ("A011021", "15", "2020-01-01", "2020-12-31", "4"),
      ("A011021", "15", "2020-01-01", "2020-12-31", "3"),
      ("A011022", "6" , "2020-01-01", "2020-12-31", "3"),
      ("A011022", "6" , "2020-01-01", "2020-12-31", "3"))
      .toDF("rep_id","sales_target","start_date","end_date","st_new")
      .withColumn("rowid",monotonically_increasing_id())

    val df2 = List(
      ("A011021","15","2020-01-01","2020-12-31","2020-01-01","2020-03-31"),
      ("A011021","15","2020-01-01","2020-12-31","2020-04-01","2020-06-30"),
      ("A011021","15","2020-01-01","2020-12-31","2020-07-01","2020-09-30"),
      ("A011021","15","2020-01-01","2020-12-31","2020-10-01","2020-12-31"),
      ("A011022","6" ,"2020-01-01","2020-06-30","2020-01-01","2020-03-31"),
      ("A011022","6" ,"2020-01-01","2020-06-30","2020-04-01","2020-06-30"))
      .toDF("rep_id","sales_target","start_date","end_date","new_sdt","new_edt")
      .withColumn("rowid",monotonically_increasing_id())


    df1.as("ds1").join(df2.as("ds2"),
      col("ds1.rowid") === col("ds2.rowid"),
      "inner")
      .orderBy(col("ds1.rep_id"),col("ds1.sales_target"),col("st_new").desc)
      .drop("rowid")
      .show()
  }

}
```

Desired output

```
+-------+------------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| rep_id|sales_target|start_date|  end_date|st_new| rep_id|sales_target|start_date|  end_date|   new_sdt|   new_edt|
+-------+------------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|A011021|          15|2020-01-01|2020-12-31|     4|A011021|          15|2020-01-01|2020-12-31|2020-04-01|2020-06-30|
|A011021|          15|2020-01-01|2020-12-31|     4|A011021|          15|2020-01-01|2020-12-31|2020-01-01|2020-03-31|
|A011021|          15|2020-01-01|2020-12-31|     4|A011021|          15|2020-01-01|2020-12-31|2020-07-01|2020-09-30|
|A011021|          15|2020-01-01|2020-12-31|     3|A011021|          15|2020-01-01|2020-12-31|2020-10-01|2020-12-31|
|A011022|           6|2020-01-01|2020-12-31|     3|A011022|           6|2020-01-01|2020-06-30|2020-04-01|2020-06-30|
|A011022|           6|2020-01-01|2020-12-31|     3|A011022|           6|2020-01-01|2020-06-30|2020-01-01|2020-03-31|
+-------+------------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: thanks, can you print the output as well.  will check the same at my end.

Comment: added the output as well @Yuva

Comment: thank you, if you see the st_new, it should 4,4,4,3 in this order, this is where am finding it difficult, any suggestions to get it right.  The st_new & new sdt, new edt are exploded data.  Thanks

Comment: and I cannot add any one on one column level validations since the number of records would vary based on the number of quarters, please see my example with rep_id A011022.  thanks

Comment: @Yuva Please verify your input . I am not able to see `A011022` anywhere

Comment: its in ds1 & df2 initial dataframes, just for reference.

Comment: can you check again, updated the output @Yuva. You may find mismatch in your and mine output because I had to assume some output

Comment: Thanks, how do we remove those invalid records, say if for rep_id A011021, in df1 & df2, i have 4 records, and i expect exactly the 4 records with columns new sdt, new edt added to df1, as per the EXPECTED RESULTs in my question. Thanks.

Comment: this is the closest I could get @Yuva. Updated the ans

Comment: Added another solution which matches your exact output @Yuva